# Obtener informacion de un producto por medio de una id

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

necesito ayuda. Tengo una pagina web **dinamica** y tengo un producto, en ese producto hay un boton que dice "**ver mas**", al darle al boton me lleva a los detalles del producto `detalles.php?product&id=48426120` (**la id cambia dependiendo del producto**).
bien, ahora quiero buscar en la base de datos el producto con la id `48426120`
y solicitar los datos del producto para poder insertar el `nombre`, `descripcion`, `precio`, etc.
pero no se como pedir los datos de la id `48426120` espero su ayuda, (*si no me explico por favor indiquenme*)

Comment: Necesitas la consulta o el código en php??  Es difícil saberlo si no nos muestras el código que hayas avanzado... Ve a [ask] para más información

Comment: nesecito el codigo php para pedir los datos del producto segun su id y poder insertarlos

Comment: ¿Necesitas la info de la base de datos para generar el listado con todos esos enlaces o para mostrar una página específica de ese producto?

Comment: nesecito una pagina especifica para cada producto, ejemplo para el producto 1: seria "detalles.php?product&id=48426120" y para el producto2 "detalles.php?product&id=54238120"

Comment: Aunque ya lo tengas resuelto, me surge una duda: ¿cómo obtienes el listado de partida? Porque lo habitual es que se obtenga a partir de un código como el que te ha sugerido @MarioGuiber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero tienes que hacer una configuración en `PHP` para poder conectar con la BD, algo como esto:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","nombredetubasededatos");
```

En el archivo `detalles.php`, puedes recoger la id del producto en una variable, para trabajar mas cómodo:

```
$idProducto = $_GET["id"];
```

Después haces la consulta a la base de datos para traer la información del producto en concreto:

```
//consulta para traer el producto
$sql = "SELECT nombre, descripcion, precio, FROM nombredetutabla WHERE idProducto = $idProducto";

//ejecutar la consulta
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);

//guardamos en un array asociativo la información del producto.
$fila = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Ahora para mostrar la información:

```
echo "El nombre del producto: " .$fila["nombre"];
echo "La descripción del producto: " .$fila["descripcion"];
echo "El precio del producto: " .$fila["precio"];
```

Ten en cuenta que los nombres que están entre las llaves de `$fila` corresponde con los campos de tu base de datos.

Esto es un ejemplo sencillo.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte, es mejor que especifiques con mayuscula los campos SELECT , FROM y WHERE, gracias

Comment: Me alegro de que haya sido de utilidad!

Answer (score 0):

De todas formas para conectarse a Mysql no usaría mysqli ya que lo recomendado para PHP es PDO que provee de una capa de abstracción para acceder a diferentes tipos de bases de datos y es lo que se utilza actualmente.

Mysqli es oficialmente obsoleta a partir de la versión 5.5 de PHP.

Comment: Estas equivocado amigo, el driver que esta obsoleto es *mysql_**, mysqli es perfectamente válido y vigente, [aquí en la doc lo puedes comprobar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration55.deprecated.php)